# Does ZF prove the propositional compactness theorem for general Boolean algebras?

Tags: set-theory, propositional-calculus, model-theory

**Propositional compactness theorem for $\{0,1\}$ algebra**: suppose that $\Gamma$ is a set of sentences of a (not necessarily enumerable) propositional language $L$. If for every finite subset $\Gamma_0 \subseteq \Gamma$ there exists an evaluation function $V_0: \text{Prop}(L) \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ such that $V(A)=1$ for every $A \in \Gamma_0$ then there exists an evaluation function $V: \text{Prop}(L) \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ such that $V(A)=1$ for every $A \in \Gamma$.

The Propositional compactness theorem for $\{0,1\}$ algebra is not provable in ZF, in fact it implies that every set can be totally ordered and this is not true in ZF.

**Propositional compactness theorem for general Boolean algebras**: suppose that $\Gamma$ is a set of sentences of a (not necessarily enumerable) propositional language $L$. If for every finite subset $\Gamma_0 \subseteq \Gamma$ there exist a general Boolean algebra $B_0$ (not necessarily the $\{0,1\}$ Boolean algebra) and an evaluation function $V_0: \text{Prop}(L) \rightarrow B_0$ such that $V(A)=1$ for every $A \in \Gamma_0$ then there exist a general Boolean algebra $B$ (not necessarily the $\{0,1\}$ Boolean algebra) and an evaluation function $V: \text{Prop}(L) \rightarrow B$ such that $V(A)=1$ for every $A \in \Gamma$.

Is the Propositional compactness theorem for general Boolean algebras provable in ZF?
Otherwise, does it imply some contraddiction in ZF?

Comment: I am very confused by your question. First, we can always take the Boolean algebra in question to be $1$, in which case the theorem is trivial. Second, what is meant by an “evaluation function”?

Comment: @MarkSaving Presumably the Boolean algebra in question should be nontrivial. An evaluation function is a map from the algebra of propositions to the Boolean algebra of truth values that commutes with the connectives in the obvious way.

Comment: @MarkSaving: when I say "general Boolean algebra" I mean a Boolean algebra with at least 2 elements. Given a general Boolean algebra $(B, \wedge, \vee, \nu, 0, 1)$ an evaluation function is a function $V: \text{Prop}(L) \rightarrow B$ such that $V(A \wedge B) = V(A) \wedge V(B)$, $V(A \vee B) = V(A) \vee V(B)$, $V(\neg A) = \nu V(A)$, $V(\top)=1$ and $V(\bot)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

First, we need to clarify the theorem. We need all Boolean algebras mentioned to be nontrivial, where “trivial” means that $\top = \bot$. Otherwise, the theorem itself is trivial: just take $B$ trivial.

Let us briefly discuss $Prop(L)$. We can construct a canonical evaluation map $\pi : Prop(L) \to Prop(L) / \equiv$, where $\equiv$ is logical equivalence and $Prop(L) / \equiv$ has the obvious Boolean algebra structure. This is a universal map in the sense that all evaluation maps $Prop(L) \to B$ factor uniquely as $f \circ \pi$, where $f : Prop(L) / \equiv \to B$ is a Boolean algebra homomorphism; conversely, given any Boolean algebra homomorphism $f : Prop(L) / \equiv \to B$, $f \circ \pi$ is an evaluation map.

Now in particular, we have a nontrivial evaluation $Prop(L) \to B$ sending all elements of a set $\Phi$ to 1 if and only if we have a nontrivial Boolean algebra homomorphism $Prop(L) / \equiv$ sending all elements of $\pi(\Phi)$ to $1$.

So we can rephrase the problem as follows. Suppose we have a Boolean algebra $C$ and some subset $\Delta \subseteq C$ and for all finite $\Delta_0 \subseteq \Delta$, there is some homomorphism $C to B_0$ sending all elements of $\Delta_0$ to $\top$, where $B_0$ is nontrivial. Then there is some homomorphism $C \to B$ sending all elements of $\Delta$ to $\top$, where $B$ is nontrivial. To translate to this case, let $C = Prop(L) / \equiv$ and $\Delta = \pi(\Gamma)$.

Recall that a filter on $C$ is a set $F \subseteq C$ closed under finite meets (that is, containing $\top$ and closed under $\land$) and upwards closed (meaning $x \leq y$ and $x \in F$ implies $y \in F$). We can define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $C$ by taking $x \sim y$ iff $\exists f \in F (x \land f = y \land f)$. Then $C / \sim$ can be made into a Boolean algebra in a unique way such that the quotient map $\pi : C \to C / \sim$ is a Boolean algebra homomorphism (in other words, the Boolean algebra operations respect $\sim$). We write the resulting Boolean algebra as $C / F$.

We say $F$ is trivial if and only if $0 \in F$. Note that $F$ is trivial if and only if $C / F$ is trivial.

Note that given any Boolean algebra homomorphism $f : C \to D$, $f^{-1}(\top)$ is a filter on C. Note that $f^{-1}(\top)$ is trivial iff $D$ is trivial. In particular, $\pi^{-1}(\top) = F$. Note that this implies that $F$ is nontrivial if and only if there exists some nontrivial $D$ and some $f : C \to D$ such that $F \subseteq f^{-1}(\top)$.

Finally, given a set $S \subseteq C$, let the filter generated by $S$ be the smallest filter containing $S$. We write this as $filter(S)$. It is easy to show that $filter(S) = \bigcup\limits_{S_0 \subseteq S, S_0 \text{ is finite }} filter(S_0)$.

Therefore, we see that $filter(\Delta)$ is trivial if and only if there exists finite $\Delta_0 \subseteq \Delta$ such that $filter(\Delta_0)$ is trivial. Conversely, $filter(\Delta)$ is nontrivial iff for all finite $\Delta_0 \subseteq \Delta$, $filter(\Delta_0)$ is nontrivial.

Now note that $filter(S)$ is nontrivial if and only if there is some nontrivial $D$ and homomorphism $f : C \to D$ such that $filter(S) \subseteq f^{-1}(\top)$. And by the definition of $filter$, we have $filter(S) \subseteq f^{-1}(\top)$ if and only if $S \subseteq f^{-1}(\top)$, that is, iff $f$ sends all elements of $S$ to $\top$.

Combining these facts, we see that for all finite $\Delta_0 \subseteq \Delta$, we have some nontrivial homomorphism $f : C \to B_0$ such that $\Delta_0 \subseteq f^{-1}(\top)$, and thus $filter(\Delta_0)$ is nontrivial. Therefore, $filter(\Delta)$ is nontrivial, and thus we have some nontrivial homomorphism $f : C \to B$ such that $\Delta \subseteq f^{-1}(\top)$.

This completes our proof.

Note: filters here act a lot like normal subgroups. You can prove analogues of the isomorphism theorems for Boolean algebras.

Comment: Thank you! Now, is it possible to prove this theorem in a constructive way? Suppose that $\Phi$ is finitely satisfiable, then for every finite $\Delta_0 \subseteq \Delta$ there is some homomorphism $f_0: C \to B_0$ sending all elements of $\Delta_0$ to $\top$. How can we construct a Boolean algebra $B$ and an homomorphism $f: C \to B$ sending all elements of $\Delta$ to $\top$? I think that to construct $B$ and $f$ we need to know every $B_0$ and every $f_0$, and to do this we need the full axiom of choice. Am I saying the right thing?

Comment: @effezeta The proof I gave is already constructive and does not use the axiom of choice. The $B$ is just $C / filter(\Delta)$.

Comment: And who is the homomorphism $f: C \to B$?

Comment: @effezeta The quotient map

Comment: I'm having problems in proving that $\text{filter}(S)=\bigcup_{S_0 \subseteq S, S_0 \text{ is finite}} \text{filter}(S_0)$. The $\supseteq$ proof is very easy, but I'm not able to do the $\subseteq$...

Comment: @effezeta First, prove the RHS is a filter. Then, prove $S$ is a subset of the RHS. Then $\subseteq$ follows from the definition of $filter(S)$.

Comment: Thanks! Does the proof of the main theorem work also for first order predicative logic?

Comment: @effezeta I’m not sure what the generalisation to first-order logic you have in mind would look like. But you can certainly choose $C$ to be a Boolean algebra derived from first-order sentences if you wish.

Comment: In the propositional case we've requested that an evaluation function $V:\text{Prop}(L)\rightarrow B$ satisfies the conditions $V(A\wedge B)=V(A)\wedge V(B)$,$V(A\vee B)=V(A)\vee V(B)$,$V(\neg A)=\nu V(A)$,$V(\top)=1$ and $V(\bot)=0$; in the first order case we've to add two more conditions that are $V(\forall xA(x))=\bigwedge_{d \in D}V(A(d))$ and $V(\exists xA(x))=\bigvee_{d \in D}V(A(d))$, where $D$ is the domain of the $x$ variable. I think that the proof fails in this case because I can evaluate $V(A(d))\in F$ for every $d\in D$ but I can have that $\bigwedge_{d \in D}V(A(d))\notin F$.

Comment: @effezeta This is still unclear. What is meant by “the domain of the $x$ variable”? This implies you already have a specific model in mind.

Comment: No, for every possible domain D it must be $V(\forall x A(x)) = \bigwedge_{d \in D} V(A[x:=d])$ and $V(\exists x A(x)) = \bigvee_{d \in D} V(A[x:=d])$.

Answer (score 1):

The general propositional compactness theorem you state is **already provable in $\mathsf{ZF}$ alone**.

First, suppose $\Gamma$ is a propositional theory which is finitely satisfiable in the usual sense. Then the **Lindenbaum algebra** of $\Gamma$ is a nontrivial Boolean algebra into which we have an obvious evaluation function $\nu$ satisfying the desired condition, namely $\nu(\varphi)=[\varphi]$.

(Recall that the Lindenbaum algebra of $\Gamma$ is the Boolean algebra coming from $\Gamma$-provable equivalence: $[\varphi]=\{\psi: \Gamma\vdash\varphi\leftrightarrow\psi\}$, $[\varphi]\le[\psi]\iff \Gamma\vdash\varphi\rightarrow\psi$, etc. Note that $\vdash$ is entirely boring in this context - choice doesn't enter into the study of propositional *deductions* at all!)

This shows that every $\{0,1\}$-finitely-satisfiable propositional theory is "general Boolean satisfiable." But for countable (or even just well-orderable) propositional theories, $\mathsf{ZF}$ already proves that general Boolean satisfiability is equivalent to $\{0,1\}$-satisfiability. Consequently, $\{0,1\}$-finite-satisfiability is equivalent to general Boolean finite satisfiability.

Comment: So, there exists an uncountable propositional theory that is general Boolean satisfable but not $\{0,1\}$ satisfable?

Comment: @effezeta No, *it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that* there exists an uncountable propositional theory that is g.B.s. but not satisfiable. Indeed, this is equivalent to the failure of the completeness theorem. In $\mathsf{ZFC}$ of course the two notions are equivalent.